# MySQL: Spatial Query to find whether a latitude/longitude point is located within a given boundary

Tags: mysql, geospatial

I'm working on google map search functionality. The vision of this is to find whether a (geolocation) point is located within a polygon or not as shown in the illustration below?

[image]

I'm using mysql 5.6.20 with Spatial extension, I know it has useful geometry functions built-in, so I will be allowed to query geocoded locations from a database directly.

My aim was to familiarize myself with geospatial functions, so I wrote up an experimental sql.

given a point geolocation: POINT(100.52438735961914 13.748889613522605)

and a polygon or boundary to be tested with was: 
POLYGON(100.49503326416016 13.766897133254545,100.55940628051758 13.746555203977,100.56266784667969 13.72170897580617,100.48885345458984 13.739051587150175)

here is my sql example:

```
SELECT ST_Within(
ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(100.52438735961914 13.748889613522605)'),
ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON(100.49503326416016 13.766897133254545,
100.55940628051758 13.746555203977,100.56266784667969 13.72170897580617,
100.48885345458984 13.739051587150175)'))
As geoFenceStatus
```

but after issuing the command, what I got in return seemed to be as follows:

```
geoFenceStatus
===============
null
```

I'm so unsure why it returned me 'null' value. since it was indicated in function documentation that this should return '1' in case a point resides within a given polygon

any advice would be appreciated, how to get my sql right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message isn't very clear but your issue is that you have an invalid Polygon. There are two problems with it:

1. You have to repeat the first point at the end -- this is to differentiate it from a LINESTRING, essentially, ie, it is closed.
2. POLYGONS start with and end with double parenthesis, ie, `POLYGON((x1 y1, x2 y2.......xn yn, x1 y1))`. This is to allow for inner rings to be delineated with single parenthesis sets inside the polygon.

See the [wikipedia WKT article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) for more information.

You should find that if you write you query as:

```
SELECT ST_Within(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(100.52438735961914 13.748889613522605)'),
             ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((100.49503326416016 13.766897133254545, 100.55940628051758 13.746555203977,100.56266784667969 13.72170897580617, 100.48885345458984 13.739051587150175,
             100.49503326416016 13.766897133254545))'))
As geoFenceStatus
```

then is should work.

Comment: You are welcome. I have looked at way too much WKT in my life

Comment: This is returning all records from table not within boundary.
SELECT ST_Within(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(1.2940879962646 103.77771377563)'), ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((1.2965335457972 103.77599716187, 1.2965335457972 103.7794303894,1.2916424443739 103.77599716187, 1.2916424443739 103.7794303894, 1.2965335457972 103.77599716187))'))As geoFenceStatus, name, reviews_cnt, latitude, longitude, photo, place_id from google_place_data order by reviews_cnt desc

Comment: @NileshKumar. What version of MySQL are you using. Not all versions of MySQL support proper intersection functions -- prior to 5.7 it only supportedf MBR operations. Any thanks for the downvote, it's always nice when people do that, after you put hundreds of hours into helping the community, and people don't even both to state their use case.

Comment: @John MySQL verion is 5.7.20

Comment: And so without any supporting evidence, such as your actual geometries or what you are expecting/what went wrong, you downvote me on another question, that clearly worked for the OP. Nice attitude . Why not ask a new question and actually put your geometries in and what you expect to happen.

Comment: I already asked question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152030/get-all-records-within-map-boundary-from-boundary-lat-and-long

I put downvote because same solution not worked for me.

It would be really helpful if you can see what i did wrong in my question.

Comment: A questoin that was closed for being unclear for exactly the same things I am complaining about here. I repeat, you ask an awful question, and then downvote a perfectly good answer because you don't understand why it isn't working for you. Disgraceful attitude.

Comment: @JohnPowell - Quick question.. In ST_GEOMFROMTEXT is there a sequence of coordinates.. Say for e.g. TopLeftCorner, TopRightCorner,BottomRightCorner, BottomLeftCorner, TopLeftCorner?

Comment: @Indark, I don't think so. I don't work on MySQL any more, switched to Postgres/Postgis a long time ago, but there is nothing in the OGC spec that suggests order is in any way important. Also, what you are asking  would only make sense for a rectangle. Having said that, if you have a spatial index on a geometry column, then this works via bounding boxes, but that has nothing to do with coordinate order, it is just an aside.

Comment: @JohnPowell Got it Thx!